# Can we do Web API Service + Multilingual Success/Error Message in Service itself?

Tags: android, ios, asp.net, architecture, asp.net-web-api2

We are doing Mobile & API Project development.
I have created the SOA Service API and it gives the business request & response.
here, new feature has to be added to implement multi language support in Mobile.
The end user can able to select any one language while Signup.

How to handle the API Success & failure Message while responding,
whether need to maintain this from Mobile side or API Side. Mobile end has maintained label & description in Mobile itself.

Here, How can we merge the Business & Presentation layer in API?
Now, Mobile is one channel but Web channel will be added in later.

which is need to follow,

1. We will create Success & Error message Code. Mobile end has to get the Code from API and get the Appropriate Message from Mobile tables based on selected language.
2. We need to maintain all the Messages in SQL table & will return to the Mobile in API response.

Please suggest me.

Comment: You will need to use localisation concept in order to show all the static text in selected language. If you want to display some text received from API in selected language than you might want to translate it on your API end and send it over to your clients.

Comment: How can we merge the Business & Presentation layer(Multi lingual) in API? what about my first approach?

Comment: I am not understanding what do you want to merge? Its a straight forward solution that you will need to translate those dynamic texts/strings on your API end.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my thought

- Create Success & Error message Code and save them on Server with specific language message and language code.
- Create API to accept message code and respond with message of specified lanuguage type.
- As it is mobile application you can cached API response to mobile app hence it will reduce server calls for getting message for specified user and for specific language for that user.
- you can expose API to send all the error message and success message code and message for specific user and for specific language at once and cache them on user mobile.

in future if you create web application it will be easy to reuse the implementation.

changing of message is also easy if required.

Introducing new language will also be easy with very few changes.